# Positive, Negative or zero in a 2D array python

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to find a way to know if a number on a matrix is positive, negative or zero. Below is my code, but I'm wondering if there is a more Pythonic way to write that. Any ideas?

```
array = np.random.randint(-10,10, size=(10,10))

def function(array):
    case1 = np.where(array < 0, -1, array)
    case2 = np.where(case1 > 0, 1, case1)
    case3 = np.where(case2 == 0, 0, case2)
    return case3

print(function(array))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should choose better functions names, `function` does not give any indication what the purpose of the function is.

In addition, a [docstring comment](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) can be used to give a short description.

But actually there is no need for a custom function because [`numpy.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) already provides the exact functionality:

> Returns an element-wise indication of the sign of a number.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.random.randint(-10,10, size=(4,4))
print(np.sign(array))
```

Output:

```
[[-1  1  1  1]
 [ 1  1  0  0]
 [ 1  1 -1  1]
 [ 1 -1  1 -1]]
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks!